# How could you draw a box.menu visually like an box.operator?

Tags: python, interface

How could you draw a box.menu visually like a box.operator.

The menu only shows up as text and works only with pie.menu but not with box.menu.

[image]

```
       #2 - BOTTOM
        box = pie.split().box().column()
        row = box.row()
        box.operator("view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected")
        #box.operator("wm.call_menu", text="Snap Menu").name="VIEW3D_MT_snap"
        box.menu("snap.more", text="Select Linked/Loop")
        box.separator() 
        box.operator("transform.mirror")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, `.menu()` entry is always drawn borderless. To make a border around you can only place it inside a box:

[image]